# How to connect a Yamaha MG82CX to a Bose L1 Pro16

Tags: audio, signal-routing

I just bought a Bose L1 pro16 and found out it really has no way to add vocal effects like reverb, chorus etc., so I bought a Yamaha MG82CX.

But how do I hook it up to the Bose?

New Bose has 3 channels

- 1 for mic
- 2 for instrument
- 3 is 1/4”  beat buddy works

Answer (score 0):

A cable.

1/4 inch TRS on each end. From stereo out out on mixer to aux in on speaker.